# Dynamic cell color in jspdf autoTable?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Is it possible to define the cell color with a nested property of the object mapped to the table ?

The JSON structure of the objects is :

```
objects: [
{
  "agent": "agent_1",
  "days": {
     day_0: {
       "code": "ABC",
       "color": "#0062cc"
     },
     day_1: {
       "code": "DEF",
       "color": "#a09494b2"
     }
  },
  {
  [...]
  }
]
```

I have a table defined like this :

```
let columns = [
  {title: "Agent", dataKey: "agent"},
  {title: "january 1st", dataKey: "day_0"},
  {title: "january 2nd", dataKey: "day_1"}]

let rows = [
  {agent: "agent_1", day_0: "ABC", day_1: "DEF"},
  [...]
]
```

All that works fine. But I'd like to set the color of each day cell dynamically, set with the color code of the corresponding object. Something like :

```
createdCell: function(cell, data) {
  {
     cell.styles.fillColor = "day_0.color";
  }
}
```

But I can't figure how to pass the data to the table. Is it possible ? Can `displayProperty` help in any way ?

Comment: Yes that would work, although you would have to set an actual color instead of ""day_0.color", like [255, 0, 0] for red.

Comment: Thanks @Simon Bengtsson for the answer. I got that, it would be `cell.styles.fillColor = "#0062cc";`. But the problem is that the color may be different for each cell. So how could I dynamically set it with the corresponding attribute ?

Comment: Something like this? `if (typeof cell.raw === 'number') { cell.styles.fillColor = [255, 0, 0] }`. I think I'm missing something can you elaborate?

Comment: Each cell in the table corresponds to a "day" object. One of the attributes of the object is a color code (like "#a09494b2" for example) which corresponds to the color to apply to the cell. But from one pdf to another, the days printed will be different, and so will be the color to apply to each cell. So I can't put in the code a direct value like "[255, 0, 0]", as it may change. I need to indicate the value of the attribute. Is it clearer now ?

Comment: Aha, so what you are asking about is how to convert a hex color to rgb values? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb Could b used something like this: `cell.styles.fillColor = hexToRgb(cell.raw)`

Comment: No, that's not the question (though your answer might help later!). The point is how to set the color value of a cell, not hard-coding it, but instead by passing an attribute value. Thanks for taking the time to try to understand my problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: In this case it was that v2.3.4 of jspdf-autotable was needed

Based on our comments discussion I think I understood your problem. You can try something like this (with the hexToRgb function from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb))

```js
let columns = [{
    title: "Agent",
    dataKey: "agent"
  },
  {
    title: "january 1st",
    dataKey: "day_0"
  },
  {
    title: "january 2nd",
    dataKey: "day_1"
  }
]

let objects = [{
  agent: "agent_1",
  day_0: {
    "code": "ABC",
    "color": "#00ff00"
  },
  day_1: {
    "code": "DEF",
    "color": "#ff0000"
  }
  // etc
}];

let doc = jsPDF()
doc.autoTable(columns, objects, {
  createdCell: function(cell, data) {
    let hex = cell.raw.color
    if (hex) {
      let rgb = hexToRgb(hex)
      cell.styles.fillColor = rgb;
      cell.text = cell.raw.code
    }
  }
});
doc.save('jhg.pdf')

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var bigint = parseInt(hex.replace('#', ''), 16);
    var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
    var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
    var b = bigint & 255;
    return [r, g, b];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.4/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

Comment: The agent prints fine, but in the day cells, I get "[object Object]" printed instead of the code ("ABC"). And the color don't print either. I tried with the code only, but with the same result. Is it because the day is a nested object with two attributes ?

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Added the hexToRgb above so you can run it now.

Comment: After many tests, I still can't make it work. The code snippet works when I run it here, I copied it exactly in my code, but I still have the [object Object]. The HextToRgb method works as well when I run it separately. It seems it doesn't recognize the cell.raw.color and cell.raw.text. Maybe it comes from the structure of the project. I'm using typescript and angular 6. Would it be the reason?

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't be. Which versions of the jspdf and which version of jspdf-autotable are you using?

Comment: jspdf : 1.4.1
jspdf-autoTable: 3.0.0-alpha.3

Comment: It worked when I switched to version 2.3.4 of jspdf-autotable. Thanks a lot for your help Simon! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just leave the answer here just in case anyone needs it.

We can use the **didParseCell** hook.

```
doc.autoTable({
      head: [[..., color]],
      body: [[..., #ffffff], [..., #ff0000]], // pass hexa value to the cell
      didParseCell: function (HookData) { 
        if (HookData.cell == undefined) 
          return; 
        // find cell taht contains the hexa value
        // the change the fillColor property
        // and set the cell value to empty
        var color = HookData.cell.text[0];
        if (color.match(/^#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}([a-fA-F0-9]{3})/g) != null) { 
          HookData.cell.styles.fillColor = hexToRgb(color);
          HookData.cell.text = [];
        }
      }
    });
```

Code to convert hexa to RGB:

```
hexToRgb(hex) {
    var bigint = parseInt(hex.replace('#', ''), 16);
    var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
    var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
    var b = bigint & 255;
    return [r, g, b];
  }
```

Package version:

**jspdf** : 2.5.1

**jspdf-autotable** :3.5.25